# flex PopUpWindow resize with percentages

Tags: apache-flex, resize, popupwindow

I have the following:

```
var win:Window = new Window();
PopUpManager.addPopUp(win,this,true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(win);
```

What about if I want the popup window to be stretched and be 80% width and height from the parent? How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var win:Window = new Window();
win.width = this.width*.8;
win.height = this.height*.8;
PopUpManager.addPopUp(win,this,true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(win);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! what in the case that my main application resizes?

Comment: If you're main application resizes, you'll have to resize the pop up manually.  You may be able to set the percentageWidth or percentageHeight properties; but I'm not sure if they work for popups.

Comment: Which part didn't work.  The precentageWidth/percentageHeight or the calculation in my original answer?

Comment: the  precentageWidth/percentageHeight doesn't work..your answer is fine except that it does not scale when i resize the mainwindow...
Maybe a listener on resize?

Comment: Yeah, that would be the other answer.  Add a listener for when the main application resizes and resize / position your popup accordingly; using the same approach I use in my main answer.

Comment: Hello again! i managed to add a listener to center my popupwindow on resize of the parent, what i want next is to resize my video previewed in this popup but in the same aspect ratio as before...how can i do that? any idea? thanks a lot beforehand!

Comment: You'll have to do some calculations to figure out the aspect ratio; then use those calculations when you resize.

Comment: Calculations to figure out the aspect ratio of the video: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_%28image%29 It sounds like a fraction thing. A 1024x768 image is at a ratio of 4:3.  Or easier just 1024/768 to give you 1.3333333 (AKA 4/3).  You just have to make sure your new size gives you the same ratio.